# How to get rid of the bottom shadow in label of the css tabs

Tags: css, tabs, positioning, shadow, box-shadow

I'm making the css tabs with shadows. How can I get rid of the bottom shadow in label? Here's an example: http://codepen.io/ekscentrysytet/pen/QbNdEB

I've tried `z-index: -1;` for `label:after` but shadow disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using pseudoelement `:before` (you have used alreasdy `after`) to make a little white rectangle to hide it?

```
label:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:15px;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-11px;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;  
}
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVeJoq)**

Comment: Looks nice! But is there another way using just z-index applied to :after?

Comment: I don't think so. Your label needs to be over your content (if you don't want the shadow content overlap your label) and your `after` is part of your label so I don't think there's a way to have an element over another while its pseudoelement is behind. (I may be wrong though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.tabinator input:checked + label:after {
     border-bottom: none;
     box-shadow: 0 -8px 15px #939393;
}
```

Comment: No. I just want to delete the shadow at the bottom of label. Top, right and left should stay there.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Still not a good solution for me. Should be as here: http://codepen.io/ekscentrysytet/pen/RPrEWY

Comment: well, if you already have the answer why don't you read it, learn it and apply?

Comment: Spent a lot of time to figure out how to apply that solution to this examle and still didn't get it. That's why I'm asking :)